# Flyout is behind SecondaryCommands

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

So what I wanted to do was to prompt the user a secondary confirmation if he wanted to change to another video. So I added a flyout. However the fly out is appearing behind the SecondaryCommands AppBarButton. Is there a way to put it in front?

Here is my code:

```
<CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="AddImage" Label="Add Image" Click="AddImage_Click" />
            <AppBarButton Name="AddVideo" Label="Add Video" Click="AddVideo_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="Browse" Label="Browse Videos" >
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <Flyout>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="You want to change to another video?"/>
                            <Button Content="Browse video" Click="Browse_Click"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Flyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Name="Status" Text="Video: HoloLens.mp4" Margin="15"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

And this is what happened:

[image]

Comment: The second command will show as Flyout and you should not show two flyout. And I think you may change the flyout to content dialog.

Comment: @lindexi Very sorry but I dont seem to understand what you are saying. Is there anyway to change the z position of the flyout? Putting in in front of "Add Image", "Add Video" and "browse videos"

Comment: The UWP can not make you do it. And I want you replace the flyout to content dialog

Comment: The flyout is not a uielement and the canvas.zindex can only change the uielement

Comment: Can you set the margin to make the flyout show near the button

Comment: @lindexi Apparently my friend did the same exact code as me but his was over the secondcommandbar. Hence I am not sure if my code has any errors or is it a possible Visual Studio thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For element display, it can be done. But not using `Flyout`.

I hope you notice that when you set `Flyout` property for the `AppBarButton` in `SecondaryCommands`, there is a right arrow on the Button. This is a very clear indication, which means the `secondary-secondary` menu.

Obviously, UWP wants to get a `MenuFlyout` or other popup layer that can display multiple levels of directory, instead of a layout that contains panel.

If you use `MenuFlyout`, you will find it appears at the top.

But if you stick to your design, there are ways to do it. When your application has a minimum version of 1809 and above, you can use `CommandBarFlyout` to achieve your purpose with its `AppBarElementContainer` property.

```xml
<AppBarButton Name="Browse" Label="Browse Videos">
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <CommandBarFlyout Placement="Top">
            <CommandBarFlyout.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarElementContainer>
                    <StackPanel Padding="15">
                        <TextBlock Text="You want to change to another video?"/>
                        <Button Content="Browse video"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </AppBarElementContainer>
            </CommandBarFlyout.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBarFlyout>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

shows here (just hold, not click):

[image: 9a953131-ac86-4546-8874-7b89f75e8f73.png]

But as @lindexi said, this is a violation of UWP design. Although it is expected to be visually responsive, it is not recommended.

I would also recommend using `ContentDialog`, or using the new control [TeachingTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/teaching-tip) from `Microsoft.UI.Xaml`, which looks better for your expectations.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This helped alot. But being a new coder, may I ask why is this a "violation of design"?

Comment: For example, when you see a button, there is a `√` icon on the button. Usually we all think this is the meaning of confirmation. But the developer used this button for the paste operation. This creates an obstacle to understanding for the user. The same is true here. The `SecondaryCommands` is equivalent to a first-level `MenuFlyout`. When the user notices that an `MenuItem` has an arrow, it usually means that it has a folding menu, but in fact we display a pop-up box, which is also a violation of user habits.